# How to make Jquery calculates percentage between 2 dates with Bootstrap UI

Tags: jquery, date, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, percentage

I'm stuck in Jquery.
What i'm Trying to achieve is using Bootstrap progress bar and make Jquery adapt the width of the bar by modifying its style.
Given a Start Date and End Date, the progress bar calculates the percentage of completion based on today's date.

It works OK when End Date isn't passed.
But problem occurs when End Date has passed it should still say: 100% and not keep calculating over 100%. If someone could have a look at it and improve my the Math which is probably missing something.

Here's my Jquery code:

```
var div_start = document.getElementById("StartDate");
var div_end   = document.getElementById("EndDate");
var start = new Date(div_start.innerHTML);
var end = new Date(div_end.innerHTML);
var today = new Date();

var total = end - start;
var progress = today - start;
var percent = Math.round(progress/ total * 100 ) + "%";
var div_per = document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0];
div_per.style.width = percent;
div_per.innerHTML = percent;
```

I've put it on http://jsfiddle.net/CjeMD/4/

Comment: There's no expression for scaling the percentage as pixels or whatever. The line `div_per.style.width = percent;` may work or may not depending on the full-scale size of `div_per`.

Comment: Second thoughts: `percent` is a string ending in "%", which makes it OK providing div_per's container (or higher level ancestor) is styled with a finite width.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the data rather than the code. As it stands your `start` and `end` dates are both earlier than `today`. If you make sure that `start` and `end` bracket `today`, then you will find that the code works fine. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjeMD/5/)

Comment: Do you want this as jQuery or as straight JavaScript? (I ask because the question is tagged as jQuery...but the code is straight JavaScript...)